# awk: Elegant way to fetch the word after a separator

Tags: regex, awk

Consider the following DB schema:

```
CREATE UNIQUE INDEX blah1 ON table1(length);
CREATE INDEX blah2 ON table3(name);
CREATE INDEX blah3 ON table3 USING btree(id);
```

I want to write a small awk script that would return the names of the indices and tables, e.g.:

```
 blah1, table1
 blah2, table2
 blah3, table3
```

I need to match the word that comes after the word `INDEX` and the word that comes after the word `ON` and ends with `(` or whitespace.

Any idea how to do it using a regex match, without iterating over all `$NF`s?

Comment: According to your specs the third line should be `blah3, table3 USING btree`  (ending with "(")

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know awk well, but this seems to work:

```
awk 'BEGIN{ FS="INDEX | ON "}{gsub(/[ (].*/,"",$3); print $2", " $3}' test.dat
```

Comment: Great. Added `/CREATE/ && /INDEX/' before `{gsub...` to match only the appropriate lines in the schema.

Answer (score 0):

```
sed 's/.*INDEX \([^ ]*\) ON \([^( ]*\)[( ].*/\1, \2/' inputfile

awk '{sub(".*INDEX ","");sub(" ON ",",");sub("[( ].*",""); sub(",",", ");print}' inputfile
```

Answer (score 0):

Works great with a Perl one-liner.

```
cat file | perl -ne '/INDEX ([a-zA-Z0-9]+) ON ([a-zA-Z0-9]+)/ && print "$1, $2\n";'
```

Returns what you wanted.